# adding two or more Values in kivy and getting the result dynamic array

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic, sum, kivy

I'm new in Kivy and i need your help .. 
I have a little question:

I need a dynamic array, which the user can enter **first value**, in the erst TextInput Box , then he can press the Button **"new line"**, he gets the possibility to enter **second value** in a new TextInput Box,than he can **press again the Button "new line"**.. he has the possibility to enter a third value in the new TextInput Box ..
at any time he can press **"Result"** .. to get the sum of this Values in a label

How can I make this **dynamic array** ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

H Lothric .. 
this is the code 
main.py

```
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


    class MainWindow(Screen):

        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.counter = 1
            self.textlist = [TextInput()]
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='Input value ' + self.counter))
            self.counter += 1
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.textlist[0])

    # function to create new inputs, that button 'new line' calls:
        def addnewtextinput(self):
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='Input value ' + self.counter))
            self.counter += 1
            self.textlist.append(TextInput())
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.textlist[-1])

    # function to get a result:
        def getresult(self):
            result = 0
            for i in self.textlist:
            # you may convert it to float if you need, like float(i.text)
                result += int(i.text)
            self.ids.label_id.text = str(result)


    class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


    class MyMainApp(App):
        def build(self):
            b1=WindowManager()
            MainWindow()
            return b1


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        MyMainApp().run()
```

and this is the main.kv

```
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 40

WindowManager:
    MainWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        # you will control that GridLayout from .py so here it's empty
        GridLayout:
            # set the id to be able to control it from .py file
            id: grid
            cols: 2

        CustButton:
            text: "new line"
            on_press: root.addnewtextinput()

        CustButton:
            text: "result"
            font_size: "30sp"
            on_press: root.getresult()

        TextInput:
            id:label_id
            font_size: 40
            multiline: True
```

this is the code

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem? Make a list of TextInputs and then take the values from it. Something like this:

```
# create a list with first text input:
self.textlist = [TextInput()]
# I don't know which layout you are using, for example BoxLayout with box variable. Add TextInput to box:
self.box.add_widget(self.textlist[0])

# function to create new inputs, that button 'new line' calls:
def addnewtextinput(self):
    self.textlist.append(TextInput())
    self.box.add_widget(self.textlist[-1])

# function to get a result:
def getresult(self):
    result = 0
    for i in self.textlist:
        # you may convert it to float if you need, like float(i.text)
        result += int(i.text)
    return result
```

Comment: hi Lothric , 
Thanks for your answer 
where should i create a list with first text input: in the main.kv or main.py

Comment: In .py file. You can create first TextInput in .kv file but it would be more complicated, you'll have to get it from there and append to the list, you don't need that extra code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in your case it would be like this:

.py file:

```
# import this
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
...
class MainWindow(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # we have to delay running that function, it will run when kv file will be ready to provide widgets by id
        Clock.schedule_once(self.getids)
        self.counter = 1
        self.textlist = [TextInput()]
        self.grid.add_widget(Label(text='Input value ' + counter))
        self.counter += 1
        self.grid.add_widget(self.textlist[0])

    # don't forget this
    grid = ObjectProperty(None)

    # function to connect layout with the variable
    def getids(self):
        self.grid = self.ids.grid

# function to create new inputs, that button 'new line' calls:
    def addnewtextinput(self):
        self.grid.add_widget(Label(text='Input value ' + self.counter))
        self.counter += 1
        self.textlist.append(TextInput())
        self.grid.add_widget(self.textlist[-1])

# function to get a result:
    def getresult(self):
        result = 0
        for i in self.textlist:
        # you may convert it to float if you need, like float(i.text)
            result += int(i.text)
        self.ids.label_id.text = str(result)

class MyMainApp(App):
        def build(self):
            self.b1 = WindowManager()
            self.b1.add_widget(MainWindow())
            return self.b1
```

.kv file:

```
<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    # don't forget to add this
    grid: grid.__self__

    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        # you will control that GridLayout from .py so here it's empty
        GridLayout:
            # set the id to be able to control it from .py file
            id: grid
            cols: 2

        CustButton:
            text: "new line"
            on_press: root.addnewtextinput()

        CustButton:
            text: "result"
            font_size: "30sp"
            on_press: root.getresult()

        TextInput:
            id:label_id
            font_size: 40
            multiline: True
```

Comment: hi Lothric , 
thanks for your help , 
i get this massage :  NameError: name 'self' is not defined .... the proplem is hier : counter = 1
    self.textlist = [TextInput()]
    self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='Input value ' + counter))
    counter += 1
    self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.textlist[0])

Comment: self.textlist = [TextInput()]

Comment: self.textlist = [TextInput()]
 NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: I've edited the code, try to put it in the init function

Comment: i've a new Proplem ,    File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/untitled2/main.py", line 14, in __init__
     self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='Input value ' + counter))
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Comment: I've edited the code, above , you can see the Error

Comment: Yeah, I know that problem, check the code once again

Comment: where is the problem do you think!

Comment: I mean I made changes in my answer, look there once again. You have to add something to .py and .kv files

Comment: grid = ObjectProperty(None)
 NameError: name 'ObjectProperty' is not defined

Comment: i have now this Proplem , he can't defined ObjectProperty

Comment: Oh, you should just import it. 'from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty'

Comment: yes ..  now Kivy Window is open, but this is only Black Window .. nothing inside

Comment: That's problems with screen manager. Try to make an object of it in build method of MyMainApp class, add there you MainWindow screen and return screen manager object from build method, not kv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207482/discussion-between-lothric-and-jan).

Comment: hi Lothric ,
i have a new Proplem
File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/untitled2/main.py", line 16, in __init__
self.grid.add_widget(Label(text='Input value ' + counter))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_widget'

... thanks